# How to fix 'set -o emacs' in .bashrc not working in ssh shell

Tags: bash, ssh

I work in an LDAP-based user and host network. My user exists on all hosts since it an LDAP user, and my user's home directory exists on all hosts as a mountpoint.

I have `~/.bash_profile` set up to source `~/.bashrc` if it exists.

Inside `~/.bashrc` my final line is `set -o emacs`.

On local shells this correctly sets the emacs option to enable emacs-style line editing after login.

But when I ssh to another host, despite my `~/.bashrc` loading everything else, the `set -o emacs` is either not applied or applied then overridden.

Therefore at the moment I have to manually `set -o emacs` each time I ssh to another host.

Is there a fix for this such that I can ssh to another host and have `set -o emacs` run automatically so immediately upon entering the interactive shell, emacs line-editing is enabled?

Comment: `ssh` starts an interactive login shell. bash does not read `.bashrc` when started as an interactive login shell.

Comment: Maybe the error is in the code in `~/.bash_profile` testing whether `.bashrc` exists? What does that code look like?

Comment: I can tell there's no error in `~/.bash_profile` because my prompt is set correctly in the SSH session and if I e.g. add an 'echo Hi There' line after the `set -o emacs` in my `.bashrc` the echo appears after SSH login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some `strace` commands we discovered that `/etc/inputrc` was being loaded after my `~/.bashrc` and that containing a `set editing-mode vi` call which overrode my `set -o emacs`. The `/etc/inputrc` doesn't exist on my local machine hence why the issue didn't occur on localhost.

This strace also identified that `~/.inputrc` is sought before `/etc/inputrc` is loaded as a fallback.

So we did `touch ~/.inputrc` to create an empty `inputrc` and voila, `set -o emacs` now works on SSH login :)

Comment: I had a similar problem where `set -o emacs` takes no effect at .bashrc. The problem was .inputrc.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` starts a brand new shell on the remote host whose standard input and standard output are forwarded by `ssh` to your local terminal. As such, you need to execute `set -o emacs` on the *remote* host, not your local host. Since `emacs`-style line editing is the default, the remote file presumably already contains a line like `set -o vim`, which you should remove.

Comment: I might have misread your question: the same home directory is mounted on all the machines?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned my user exists on all hosts and my user's home directory exists on all hosts, i.e. my "local" .bashrc and .bash_profile exist on every machine and are what's loaded when I ssh into a remote host.